# JavaScript scan for words and make into link

Tags: javascript

I need pure JavaScript to use an array of specified words and URLs to read a webpage and convert any matching words into links. The Google Gods have neglected to return any helpful examples:( Any help would be great!

I found this on a site somewhere :

```
FUNCTION linkWord(obj){
  FOR(i IN obj){
    VAR x = document.body.innerHTML;
    VAR linkStart = '<a href="'+obj[i]+'">';     
    VAR linkEnd = '</a>';     
    VAR reg = NEW RegExp ('\\b' + i + '\\b','g');
    x = x.replace(reg, linkStart + i + linkEnd);
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
  }
}

linkWord ({
  'funny':'http://www.example.com',
  'another':'http://icant.co.uk'
});
```

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, so I don't think that will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
funny another

<script>
var linkWord = function(obj){
  for(i in obj){
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;
    var linkStart = '<a href="'+obj[i]+'">';
    var linkEnd = '</a>';
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b(" + i + ")\\b","g");
    x = x.replace(reg, linkStart + i + linkEnd);
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
  }
}

linkWord({
  'funny':'http://www.example.com',
  'another':'http://icant.co.uk'
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Study it. Work out why yours didn't work.

Comment: what about `<div id="funny">blib</div>`?

Comment: Oh, @Yoshi you wanted me to literally write his whole script for him? Nah I'm alright, he can work out some of it.